# Referrer/redirect URL on heading element

Tags: wordpress, elementor

How heading title to be automatically renamed with the referrer URL?

For example if I enter page.com (where is elementor heading element added) from example.com, how heading title to be automatically renamed with “example.com”? (SEE IMAGE)[the domain I sell is www.example.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i54hx.jpg)
I tried with wp_get_referer() but it doesn't work. here is the code:

```
   <?php $result=wp_get_referer(); echo $result; ?>
```

I need this, because I create elementor template. The purpose is that I want to sell domains. So for every domainname.com I want to redirect to elementor template where heading element will be automatically renamed with the domain I sell.

Comment: Can you share what code you've written to this point as a [mre], along with a succinct explanation of where you're getting stuck in the attempt? [ask]

Comment: I see you've added your "attempt" at meeting the requirement; can you point to the statement in the code provided that you expect to set the "*heading title... automatically... with the referrer URL*"? Can you also provide a bit more clarity on the problem statement? ("*it doesn't work*" isn't particularly helpful, and is not a substitute for pertinent debugging information including error messages, expected vs. actual behavior, etc.)